# Prove using axioms that $1 \neq 0$ - checking

Tags: real-numbers, solution-verification

Let $1=0$ we know that $x \cdot y=0$ if $x=0$ or $y=0$ so

$1(1-1)=0 $ if $1=0$ or $1=1$ but $1=1$ is contradiction since we assume that $1=0$ so $1 \neq 0$

Is my prof correct ? If not how should it look like ?

Comment: Not a contradiction. I don't know what axioms you are using, but the field ones (i.e. the ones with multiplication, addition, identities, etc) aren't going to give you any contradictions since $\{0\}$ is a valid field. Edit: I guess actually a zero ring is not a field. My mistake!

Comment: I don't think you can prove it. It's an assumption for $\mathbb{R}$ to be a nontrivial field.

Comment: @BruceZheng The axioms I take for a field do not have $\{0\}$ as a valid field...  Sure, a commutative division ring, but not a field.  To be complete, the definitions I use are to say that $(F,+,\cdot,0,1)$ is a field if both $(F,+,0)$ and $(F\setminus\{0\},\cdot,1)$ are abelian groups and distributivity holds. Since there is no group structure on $\emptyset$, we must have $F\neq \{0\}$.

Comment: @mariuszCzarnecki it is important that you include your axioms since there are clearly different accepted definitions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is $\{0\}$ a field?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427078/is-0-a-field)

Comment: You made a few assumptions.  The proof is faulty.  Firstly, what does $1-1$ even mean? Is subtraction defined in your axioms? Secondly, do you know that $1-1=0$, because that seems like your second leap?  Thirdly, what does $1-1=0$ have to do with $1=1$; there seems to be a disconnect there because I dont see how you went from $1\cdot 0 = 0$ to $1\cdot(1-1)=0$?  Is substitution even allowed?  Have you defined multiplication in your axioms? Lastly, how do you know that $1\ne 0$ already, because if you concluded $1=1$ but assumed $1=0$ then what is the contradiction? There doesnt seem to be one.