# Soft question about integral domain

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Here is a soft question that I am dealing with. Please tell me if it's correct or not.

> Suppose $A$ is a commutative ring with unity. Is $A$ a prime ideal of $A$?

I think the answer is true, because we know $I$ is an integral domain iff $R/I$ is an integral domain. But $A/A = 0.$ So it's an integral domain. So$A$ is a prime ideal in $A$ Tell me if I argument is right or wrong. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Usually when we consider prime ideals, we define them to be proper ideals, i.e. ideals that are not the whole of $A$.

Comment: Near-duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326505/is-the-zero-ring-a-domain

Comment: Also relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427078/is-0-a-field

Comment: So mostly it deoends on the convention. But I don't understand the argument behind whole ring not being a prime ideal. In the questions they discussed about 0 being any domain, while not about 0 being an integral domain. So I should consider 0 in general not an integral domain and the proceed further?

Comment: That's not a soft question.

Comment: @user631697 you could call it a convention, but if so, this is really one of those conventions that has nearly 100% of the usage. I have never seen the alternative used even once in a text or paper.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually taken as part of the definition that an integral domain must not be the zero ring.

For example, [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain) (first sentence of the article, note the word “nonzero”), and in the standard references (Atiyah & Macdonald, Matsumura, Lang, etc.).