# Why is $F=\{0\}$ a field?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Context: I am new to this. I started my course yesterday.

I know that the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ are required to satisfy the field axioms. So how can $F=\{0\}$ be a field?
Recall the additive and multiplicative identity:
there exist 2 different elements $0$ and $1$ in $F$ such that $ a + 0 = a$ and $a \cdot  1 = a$

But there is only one element in $F$? Shouldn't that mean that this rule has not been satisfied and thus $F$ is not a field?

**My teacher mentioned something about $0=1$ can someone explain that?**

Update my lecture notes:

[image]

Comment: Your teacher is partially correct, although instead of a field I think your teacher implies an Abelian group. An [Abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group) with one element $G=\{e\}$, has an element that acts as both the additive identity, (traditionally notated as $0$) and the multiplicative identity ($1$).For all elements, $a\in G$, $e$ satisfies the multiplicative identity $a*e = e$, and the additive identity $a+e = a$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427078/is-0-a-field?rq=1

Comment: If that's what your teacher said, they are *incorrect*. "Field" universally means $0 \neq 1$. It's much like the fact that 1 is not considered a prime number--we'd constantly be adding silly assumptions if we allowed $\{0\}$ to be a field.

Comment: Agreed. If you want $\{0\}$ to be something, it can be a ring.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element

Comment: {$0$} is not a field. Every common definition of a field assumes $0\ne 1$. And even if we allow this field it has no interesting properties whatsoever.

Comment: @Servaes I think just posting that link without comment confuses matters. The relevant point is that the "field with one element" is not actually a field.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Hi Mr Swason, thanks for commenting. I updated my lecture notes. He did say that $0≠1$

Answer (score 8):

Under the usual axioms $\{0\}$ is *not* a field. E.g., if $F$ is s field and $0$ its additive neutral then $F\setminus\{0\}$ is a group under multiplication - but groups cannot be empty. Put differently, one often takes $0\ne 1$ as one of the axioms of a field.

Comment: I would replace *often* with *always*. But possibly we can locate people who think it is not necessary?

Comment: Hello Mr von Eitzen, I updated my lecture notes