# Why are integral domains required to be non-zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Why are integral domains required to be non-zero? I understand this is mostly a convention, but it seems somewhat arbitrary to me as of now. Is there any known theorem that fails if we allow the $0$ ring to be considered an integral domain? Or is it because of purely historical reason? I'm wondering the same for, PID, fields, etc; but since they are supposed to be a subset of integral domains, then the corresponding question reduces to the question of integral domains.

Comment: Well, for instance, it often leads to some trivial counterexamples that no one really wants to consider. The zero ring just doesn't behave in the same way many other domains/fields/whatever do. While focused on fields, you can find some discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427078/is-0-a-field)

Comment: I like to be able to say that, in an integral domain, any finite product of non-zero elements is non-zero. If the zero ring were  called an integral domain, then the empty product would be a counterexample.